# Spring Transaction on server shutdown

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions, acid

Spring @Transaction does not rollback if the server shuts down in the middle of a transactional method. But that violates the atomicity principle of transactions. Why is that?

That is, if my code looks like this:

```
@Transactional
public void method() {
    write();
    // server shuts down
    write();
}
```

The first write is not rolled back.

Comment: The first write shouldn't even be committed, so there is something else wrong with your setup.

Comment: I am using a standard SB 2.7 application with a JpaRepository

Comment: Which database? What does the `write` do? The fact that you use "standard" things doesn't mean you are using them correctly.